# ORA-00905: missing keyword in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

I have 2 tables category and coupon_category in my oracle database

I am making query

```
select coupon_category.coupon  from coupon_category  JOIN category;
```

which gives me error

```
SQL>    select coupon_category.coupon  from coupon_category INNER JOIN category;
        select coupon_category.coupon  from coupon_category INNER JOIN category
                                                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

What is the mistake I am making?

Comment: You are missing the `ON` or `USING` clause. These describe how the two tables should be joined.

Comment: select coupon_category.coupon  from coupon_category INNER JOIN category where coupon_category.coupon=category.id;
 is the actual query I want to run

Comment: What you are putting in your `WHERE` is really the join condition. Try subbing out that keyword for `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be a misunderstanding of join syntax. Your current code is combining the old and new syntax for joining two tables. The proper join can be accomplished by using either correctly (with the `ON` syntax preferred).

```
select coupon_category.coupon from coupon_category INNER JOIN category ON coupon_category.coupon=category.id;
--OR
select coupon_category.coupon from coupon_category, category where coupon_category.coupon=category.id;
```

Comment: Elaborating Hep's answer: The INNER JOIN takes all rows from both tables, 120,000 combinations in all if one table has 1,000 rows and the other 120, and evaluates the "ON" condition. You can see how this is logically equivalent to the other syntax (old, deprecated, proprietary Oracle). Another way to write it with a WHERE condition is to write SELECT... FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 WHERE (condition). In fact, the comma-syntax is a different (old, deprecated, not recommended) syntax that means **exactly** cross join (which does a Cartesian product of the tables, with no ON or WHERE condition).